# my google contacts do not have All Contacts

Tags: google, google-contacts

This is funny, people are claiming (http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Mobile/thread?tid=04935f1855c27f2a&hl=en) that there is something called `All Contacts` group in Google Contacts.

But I don't have it in my account:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That feature/category is gone for a while. Now your contacts are grouped into `My contacts` and `Other contacts` plus all the groups you have created.

`All Contacts` used to contain your contacts plus other contacts, which are contacts that you emailed but you didn't add to your contact list.

Comment: then how do we sync all our contacts into our iphone now? help me with this: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21353/how-do-i-make-iphone-sync-all-contacts-from-google-contacts-into-iphone thx!

Comment: @Pacerier If you want to sync all you contacts then add the contacts from your Other contacts to your contacts. If you want to have them on your iphone why not having them as gmail contacts as well?